# `gets': Invalid argument - <STDIN> (Errno::EINVAL) in ruby

Tags: ruby, command-prompt, notepad

I tried simple ruby script to print name. I used notepad to code and command prompt to display the output and to get input from user.

My code in notepad (hello.rb) :

```
def hello(name)
   puts "hello,#{name}"
end
puts "enter name"
name=gets.chomp
puts hello(name)
```

when i tried getting input from user,i got an error

`` `gets': Invalid argument - <STDIN> (Errno::EINVAL) from hello.rb:6:in `gets' from hello.rb:6:in `<main>' ``

but when i tried it in online compiler its working fine. how to resolve this? Thanks is advance!

Comment: Hi Nimmi, the error looks like it's due to the ruby not running in a shell that accepts input.  how are you running this offline?

Comment: @Jad ,I installed ruby application from shared folder and also i used notepad(text editor) to code ,runs script in command line prompt in offline. it's working fine if i don't get input from user ```puts "hello"=>hello``` is it anything to do with ruby environmental setup!?Thanks!

Comment: I think it's likely to be how you're executing the script in your ruby environment.  I believe that the tool that you're calling ruby from isn't an "interactive shell" so can't get input.